# Google meet draining battery

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, power-management, laptop, battery

I am on ubuntu 18.04(`4.15.0-45-generic`) using chrome `Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) unknown (64-bit)`.

About a month ago google meet started draining my battery like crazy. 1 minute of video chat takes about 4 percent of my battery. Initially I thought this is caused by the battery so I bought a brand new battery and replaced it. Still I observe the same behavior. Then I also noted that when using meet chrome takes about 2 CPUs on average all the time.

This issue is specific to linux (or maybe to my setup) because a colleague did the same experiment and his battery usage was fine (and there was not excessive CPU usage).

My laptop is lenovo thinkpad w540.

Does anyone have ideas of how I can fix this? It makes doing video calls impossible for me.

Comment: Battery drain on macOS too, using Safari. From 100% to 30% in 2h without camera and microphone. Seems like Google Meets is using a lot of System resources. To improve battery life use Chrome without any extensions (add-blockers,... etc) and pray. Definitely not a great experience